# Is there any std::replace_if equivalent which enables using lambda for the new value

Tags: c++

Say if I have the following class and I want to replace **AA** where **a_** is equal to 1.

```
struct AA {
    AA(int a) :a_(a) {};
    int a_;
};

std::vector<AA> aa{ AA(1), AA(2), AA(4) };
std::replace_if(aa.begin(), aa.end(), [](const AA& aa1) {return aa1.a_ == 1;}, newValue);
// Here I want the newValue to be say AA(old.a_ +1).
```

```
template <class _ForwardIterator, class _Predicate, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX17
void
replace_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Predicate __pred, const _Tp& __new_value)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (__pred(*__first))
            *__first = __new_value;
}
```

From the implementation in clang shown above, I don't see any way that I can use a lambda as the newValue here.

So my question is that I want to replace some value in a vector with a new value that depends on the old value, is there any way to avoid doing a **find_if**, then manipulate the data stored and then replace it with the new value? without rewriting my own replace_if

edit:
I know that I can just reinvent the wheel by doing below:

```
template <class _ForwardIterator, class _Predicate, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX17
void
replace_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Predicate __pred,_Tp __new_value)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (__pred(*__first))
            *__first = __new_value(*first);
}
```

Bust just want to know if there is an existing solution in stl or boost.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know that I can reinvent the wheel by just modifying the implementation, but just wondering if there is any existing solution in stl algorithm or boost.  and I am not looking to modify the value stored in the vector, it is more like creating a new obj based on the old one and replacing the old one.

Comment: "*I am not looking to modify the value stored in the vector*" The difference between assigning a new value which is built from the old value and modifying the value is pure sophistry.

Comment: @NicolBolas fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Such an algorithm does not exist because it would basically be pointless and needlessly verbose compared to any of the reasonable alternatives. You want an algorithm that takes two user-provided functions: one which takes a `const&` of the value type, and one which takes a `&` of the value type. The former returns whether the value should be modified, and the latter modifies it.

You may as well have a single functor that both tests and modifies the value. At which point, the algorithm in question is just `for_each`, or range-based `for`.

Consider the code clarity for the alternatives:

```
std::replace_if(aa.begin(), aa.end(),
    [](const AA& aa1) {return aa1.a_ == 1;},
    [](AA& aa1) {aa1 = AA(aa1.a_ + 1); });

std::for_each(aa.begin(), aa.end(),
    [](AA& aa1) {
      if(aa1.a_ == 1)
        aa1 = AA(aa1.a_ + 1);
    });

for(auto& aa1 : aa)
{
  if(aa1.a_ == 1)
    aa1 = AA(aa1.a_ + 1);
}
```

I would say that the 3rd one is the cleanest, followed by the second. It puts all of the user-provided code in one place. It makes it clear that the conditional and the assignment are all part of the same operation, rather than being in separate functors.

Comment: Thank you, Nicol, but just wondering you can also say the same thing with std::replace_if, since under the hood, it is just the same as doing a for loop and finding the one that fits the condition, and then replacing it with a given new value, which is basically your 2 and 3. I don't quite get why a lambda version is pointless and needless given that the original one is useful and needed.

Comment: if there isn't any existing algorithm to do so, I would do the third one as well, but just want to get my head around that if there is an existing one, if not, why.

Comment: @X.J.L: `replace_if` serves a purpose, as the only user-provided code is the condition. What happens if the condition succeeds or fails is part of the algorithm; the user can only change the condition. If the entire body of the loop is user provided, it's just a verbose form of `for_each`.

Answer (score -1):

No, `std::replace_if()` does not support a lambda (or any other callable type) for the `newValue`.

However, it does allow any type that is implicitly convertible to the iterator's `value_type`, including types with a conversion `operator` implemented.  But, as you can see in the implementation you showed, there is simply no way to access the "old" value being placed so you can compute a new value from it, like you want to do.  Given the implementation shown, the only possibility I see would be to have `AA` overload `operator=` to perform addition instead of assignment, which is not a good idea.

Otherwise, `std::replace_if()` is simply not the right tool for you.

You could implement your own function, eg:

```cpp
template <class _ForwardIterator, class _CmpPredicate, class _ModPredicate>
inline void
modify_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _CmpPredicate __cmp_pred, _ModPredicate __mod_pred)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (__cmp_pred(*__first))
            __mod_pred(*__first);
}

modify_if(aa.begin(), aa.end(),
    [](const AA& aa1) { return aa1.a_ == 1; },
    [](AA& aa1) { aa1.a_ += 1; }
);
```

Otherwise, just use a `std::find_if()` loop instead, eg:

```cpp
auto cmp = [](const AA& aa1) { return aa1.a_ == 1; };

auto iter = std::find_if(aa.begin(), aa.end(), cmp);
while (iter != aa.end())
{
    iter->a_ += 1;
    iter = std::find_if(iter+1, aa.end(), cmp);
}
```

Or, you could use `std::transform()` instead, eg:

```cpp
std::transform(aa.begin(), aa.end(), aa.begin(), 
    [](const AA& aa1) {
        int a = aa1.a_;
        if (a == 1) a += 1;
        return AA(a);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as stated in my question. I was wondering If there is an existing solution that I can use to avoid looping multiple times by using find_if.

Comment: The only solution with `replace_if()` would be to have `AA` overload `operator=` to perform addition instead of assignment. Otherwise, no.

Comment: yes, I am fully aware of that, just want to know if there is anything like a replace_if in boost or stl that can take a lambda, just want to confirm before reimplementing replace_if that takes a lamabda in my project.

Comment: No, there is no, which can easily be seen by looking at the references for those libraries.

Comment: Got it, Thanks Remy.